# spaghetti code for lunch: refactoring a bunch of fields that always get initialized

Tags: c#

blah - not even sure if that is the correct way to say it. Basically I have this

```
public class XmlAccess
{
    public XmlAccess() { }

    public string ApplicationPath = "";

    public string DBServer = ConfigurationManager.AppSettings["DB2_Server"];
    public string DBName = ConfigurationManager.AppSettings["DB2_Database"];
    public string DBLogIn = ConfigurationManager.AppSettings["DB2_User"];
}
```

I am trying to create some seams for some unit tests and have pulled out a lot of interfaces which is great but I have this thing (code above) trying to initialize all these fields (that's just a sample - it goes on and on...) when it fires up. Anyone have any suggestions as to how to refactor this? I have never had to do this sort of major refactor of "old code" but I am sure others have. The way it is handling those variables is silly and untestable but I am not sure what to do about it and it's holding me up.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

Does any code set those fields?

Turn them into properties, then extract the interface that includes the properties. I recommend against letting any code set them, if at all possible.

Comment: Yeah - I ended up making them all Properties and creating an interface.

Answer (score 1):

Try decoupling `XmlAccess` from the configuration system:

```
public class XmlAccess
{
    public XmlAccess(string applicationPath, string dbServer, string dbName, string dbLogIn)
    {
        ApplicationPath = applicationPath;
        DBServer = dbServer;
        DBName = dbName;
        DBLogIn = dbLogIn
    }

    public string ApplicationPath;
    public string DBServer;
    public string DBName;
    public string DBLogIn;
}
```

Then, when you need an instance, access the configuration file:

```
new XmlAccess(
    "",
    ConfigurationManager.AppSettings["DB2_Server"],
    ConfigurationManager.AppSettings["DB2_Database"],
    ConfigurationManager.AppSettings["DB2_User"]);
```

In your unit tests, you can pass whatever values makes sense for the test and skip the configuration system entirely:

```
new XmlAccess("", "TestServer", "TestName", "TestLogIn");
```

Comment: The only problem there is that there are like 40 of these properties, I just read Uncle Bob, "The ideal number of arguments for a function is zero (niladic). Next comes one (monadic), followed closely by two (dyadic)." so I don't want to go that route.

Comment: @Kenn: That probably indicates `XmlAccess` has too many responsibilities. Have you considered refactoring it so it has fewer dependencies?

Comment: Instantiating the class w/o arguments and setting the properties that you need changed after the fact would PROBABLY work a bit better... But I think I already suggested that.

Answer (score 0):

I believe we call "old code" "legacy code".

But, since those variables are public you should be able to change them to something more appropriate before you run your tests.

Comment: Right - "old code" was substitute for "messy garbage that's driving me insane", I felt like the term legacy code was giving it too much credit.

Answer (score 0):

I would create a new class called something like DBServer to replace those properties you listed.

```
public class DBServer{

    public string  Host {get;set;}
    public string  Name {get;set;}
    public string  Login {get;set;}
}
```

But I would need to look at the rest of the properties to know how many other classes were needed or were appropriate. I'm reminded of [this article by Jeff Atwood](http://www.codinghorror.com/blog/2006/05/code-smells.html) about code smells.

> Large classes, like long methods, are difficult to read, understand,
>   and troubleshoot. Does the class contain too many responsibilities?
>   Can the large class be restructured or broken into smaller classes?